# How does @login_required ensure that the user is actually logged in?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

From looking at the code:

```
def login_required(func):
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_app.login_manager._login_disabled:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

it handles 3 cases:

1. the login is disabled in the login manager
2. login is enabled but the user is not authenticated (anonymous user)
3. login is enabled and the user is authenticated (which is always True for 'User').

So which part of the code actually checks whether the user is actually logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my own question actually: it's that if the user is not logged in, `current_user` is an anonymous user. The `is_authenticated()` can return False for anonymous users (not logged in) and `True` for actual users.